# Editable terminal border in cmd

Tags: python, windows, cmd

How can I create a simple terminal border that can easily be printed in?

Something like this is perfect

```
┌──────────┐
│  text    │
│  text    │
├──────────┤
│ input    │
└──────────┘
```

I've seen modules like Npyscreen and a UI like this would be perfect although this is not what my requirements need. It needs to be way easier for my purpose (Text based RPG game). If someone can recommend me a module or give me a simple way on how to replicate this then that'd be great!

Comment: Have you looked for what you need using [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)

Comment: I've also seen this, although from what I read on the docs is not explaing on how to fill it up with characters.

Comment: Are you talking about Windows' `cmd` command-line console?

Comment: yes, the application will be ran in windows cmd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using curses :

```py
import curses
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
screen.keypad(True)
left_border = '│'
right_border = '│'
top_border = '─'
bottom_border = '─'
separator = '─'
top_left = "┌"
top_right = "┐"
bottom_left = "└"
bottom_right = "┘"
left_junction = "├"
right_junction = '┤'


def refresh_screen(current_text, info):
    screen.clear()  # clear
    rows, cols = screen.getmaxyx()  # get screen rows and columns
    screen.addstr(0, 0, top_left)  # top left corner
    screen.addstr(0, 1, top_border * (cols - 3))  # top border
    screen.addstr(0, cols - 2, top_right)  # top right corner
    for i in range(1, rows - 1):
        screen.addstr(i, 0, left_border)  # left border
    for i in range(1, rows - 1):
        screen.addstr(i, cols - 2, right_border)  # right border
    screen.addstr(rows - 1, 0, bottom_left)  # bottom left corner
    screen.addstr(rows - 1, 1, bottom_border * (cols - 3))  # bottom border
    screen.addstr(rows - 1, cols - 2, bottom_right)  # bottom right corner
    screen.addstr(rows - 3, 0, left_junction)  # left junction
    screen.addstr(rows - 3, 1, separator * (cols - 3))  # separator
    screen.addstr(rows - 3, cols - 2, right_junction)  # right junction
    cursorx = 1
    cursory = 1
    # write the info text
    for char in info:
        if char == '\n': # deal with newlines
            cursorx = 1
            cursory += 1
        else:
            screen.addstr(cursory, cursorx, char)  # add character
        cursorx += 1  # increment cursor position
        if cursorx >= cols - 3:  # if cursor x is over right border, carriage return
            cursorx = 1
            cursory += 1
    # write the current user input
    screen.addstr(rows - 2, 1, " " + current_text)
    screen.refresh()


info = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet " * 10
user_input = ""
refresh_screen(user_input, info)
while True:
    key = screen.getkey()
    if ord(key) == 127: # backspace
        user_input = user_input[:-1]
    else:
        user_input += key
    if key == '\n':
        # user entered something
        # do_something(user_input)
        user_input = ""
    refresh_screen(user_input, info)
```

However, this does not handle the Backspace key or a text overflow (info text larger than the text zone).

**EDIT:** I added support for deleting with backspace.

`info` is the variable containing the text in the top zone (here lorem ipsum ten times) and `user_input` contains the current user input. You can change the variable declarations at the top to change the type of the border.

It gives something like this :

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum do │
│lor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet l │
│orem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dol │
│or sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet lorem ipsum dolor sit amet    │
│                                                                     │
│                                                                     │
│                                                                     │
│                                                                     │
│                                                                     │
│                                                                     │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ user input here                                                     │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:
[npyscreen | How do I edit other screens/forms, and customize it with widgets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68580656/npyscreen-how-do-i-edit-other-screens-forms-and-customize-it-with-widgets)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import npyscreen
class TestApp(npyscreen.NPSApp):
    def main(self):
        # These lines create the form and populate it with widgets.
        # A fairly complex screen in only 8 or so lines of code - a line for each control.
        F  = npyscreen.Form(name = "Welcome to Npyscreen",)
        t  = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name = "Text:",)
        fn = F.add(npyscreen.TitleFilename, name = "Filename:")
        fn2 = F.add(npyscreen.TitleFilenameCombo, name="Filename2:")
        dt = F.add(npyscreen.TitleDateCombo, name = "Date:")
        s  = F.add(npyscreen.TitleSlider, out_of=12, name = "Slider")
        ml = F.add(npyscreen.MultiLineEdit,
               value = """try typing here!\nMutiline text, press ^R to reformat.\n""",
               max_height=5, rely=9)
        ms = F.add(npyscreen.TitleSelectOne, max_height=4, value = [1,], name="Pick One",
                values = ["Option1","Option2","Option3"], scroll_exit=True)
        ms2= F.add(npyscreen.TitleMultiSelect, max_height =-2, value = [1,], name="Pick Several",
                values = ["Option1","Option2","Option3"], scroll_exit=True)

        # This lets the user interact with the Form.
        F.edit()

        print(ms.get_selected_objects())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = TestApp()
    App.run()
```